# How do host machine know about the private key in the machine which is doing ssh in it [ssh-copy-ip method ]

Tags: 18.04, ssh, authentication

With this method:

```
ssh -i   private key  ubuntu_A@1.2.3.4
```

I am telling that here is my private key and `ubuntu_A` matches my private key with the public key in `authorized_keys`.

I am confused with `ssh-copy-id` method from  `ubuntu_B`. I did:

```
ssh-copy-id 1.2.3.4
```

and it copied my public key in `authorized_key` file.

Now, when I do `ssh 1.2.3.4` I can log in into `ubuntu_A`. With this method how `ubuntu_A` knows about the private key in the `ubuntu_B`.

How can I see it is verifying the private key?.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the remote server doesn't see your privkey itself.  Your system offers the ID of your key (which matches the ID on the pubkey) to the server to start the process.

From Digital Ocean tutorials on [Understanding the SSH Encryption and Connection Process](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process), specifically the section on "Authenticating the User’s Access to the Server" and just the key authentication process bits:

> The public key is used to encrypt data that can only be decrypted with
> the private key. The public key can be freely shared, because,
> although it can encrypt for the private key, there is no method of
> deriving the private key from the public key.
>
> Authentication using SSH key pairs begins after the symmetric
> encryption has been established as described in the last section. The
> procedure happens like this:
>
> 1. The client begins by sending an ID for the key pair it would like to authenticate with to the server.
> 2. The server check’s the authorized_keys file of the account that the client is attempting to log into for the key ID.
> 3. If a public key with matching ID is found in the file, the server generates a random number and uses the public key to encrypt the
>    number.
> 4. The server sends the client this encrypted message.
> 5. If the client actually has the associated private key, it will be able to decrypt the message using that key, revealing the original
>    number.
> 6. The client combines the decrypted number with the shared session key that is being used to encrypt the communication, and calculates
>    the MD5 hash of this value.
> 7. The client then sends this MD5 hash back to the server as an answer to the encrypted number message.
> 8. The server uses the same shared session key and the original number that it sent to the client to calculate the MD5 value on its
>    own. It compares its own calculation to the one that the client sent
>    back. If these two values match, it proves that the client was in
>    possession of the private key and the client is authenticated.
>
> As you can see, the asymmetry of the keys allows the server to encrypt
> messages to the client using the public key. The client can then prove
> that it holds the private key by decrypting the message correctly. The
> two types of encryption that are used (symmetric shared secret, and
> asymmetric public-private keys) are each able to leverage their
> specific strengths in this model.

(Unfortunately, there is no way to simplify this explanation from the above further.)